# Azure S2 Database Automatically creating and deleting a database every day

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I currently have an Azure S2 database running via the new Azure Portal.

I notice my billing was higher than it should be and after investigating further, I noticed there were new databases appearing every day then disappearing.

Basically, something is running a CreateDatabase and DeleteDatabase event every evening, and I'm being charged an extra hour each day.

Microsofts response is:
"Our Operations Team investigated the issue and found that these databases did indeed exist in a 1 hour windows at midnight PST every day. It looks like you may have some workload which is doing this unknowingly or an application with permissions which is unknowingly creating these databases and then dropping them. "

I haven't set up any scripts to do this, and I have no apps running that could be doing this.

How can I find out what's happening?

Regards

Ben

Comment: Do you have an azure automation  runbook doing this?

Comment: Can it be a scheduled export?

Comment: You might consider setting up SQL Auditing on your database (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-auditing-get-started) to gain more insights. Or you might consider rolling your DB password or revoking the create database permission?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm not sure what Azure Automation Runbook is? I don't have any scheduled exports. The strange thing is, the database is getting copied with DBName_<guid> then getting deleted 20 minutes later...

Comment: I have also this issues... When I look at the list of 'Deleted Databases' in old portal, I see databases name_GUID that are deleted daily. Can this be somehow related to Entity Framework? Do you use EF in your project?